# Finding peaks in vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to find "peaks" in a vector, i.e. elements for which the nearest neighboring elements on both sides that do not have the same value have **lower** values.

So, e.g. in the vector

```
c(0,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,7)
```

there are peaks at positions 5,6,7,12 and 14

[Finding local maxima and minima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima-in-r) comes close, but doesn't quite fit.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer in the link you gave? ie which(diff(sign(diff(tt)))==-2)+1

Comment: It only returns `12` since that's the only element for which both **immediate** neighbors have lower values.

Comment: Nice question, and thanks too for showing your thought/research so far with that excellent link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work. The call to `diff(sign(diff(x)) == -2` finds peaks by, in essence,  testing for a negative second derivative at/around each of the unique values picked out by `rle`.

```
x <- c(0,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,7)

r <- rle(x)
which(rep(x = diff(sign(diff(c(-Inf, r$values, -Inf)))) == -2, 
          times = r$lengths))
# [1]  5  6  7 12 14
```

(I padded your vector with `-Inf`s so that both elements 1 and 14 have the possibility of being matched, should the nearest different-valued element have a lower value. You can obviously adjust the end-element matching rule by instead setting one or both of these to `Inf`.)

Comment: ... and only now do I click through to the linked question and see that Ben Bolker and Tommy there used essentially the same approach and explanation as I did here! I guess that's a sign that this is about as good as you can do.

Comment: Like I said: It was close to what I wanted but I couldn't quite figure out how to change it to achieve what I wanted. Thanks for even taking the time to explain how your solution work!