# Find peaks in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm having troubles with: finding peaks in R plot. 
 What I have is `data.frame` called `data` that looks like this:

```
      x        y
1   177.76  1366.20
2   177.98  1366.20 
3   178.20  1366.20
4   178.42  1333.02
5   178.64  1358.21 
6   178.85  1384.02
7   179.07  1382.58 
...................
```

After

```
plot(data$x, data$y, type="l")
```

[image: plot]

Is there a function that automatically finds peaks? 
I know about `findPeaks()` but I need `time.series` for that. 
Thanks

Comment: do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945113/finding-peaks-in-vector answer your question?  If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks man! After a long and hard work [picture](http://i60.tinypic.com/23hm2de.jpg) :)