# Finding local maxima/minima in R

Tags: r

I've got a hole bunch of data (10,000 - 50,000 values for each series of measurements) and I'm interested in automatically identifying local maxima/minima out of the density estimation of the distribution of these values. In fact, I assume that usually there should be two peaks, separated by a pit, and I'd like to find that pit which separates the two peaks from each other in order to split the data into two parts for further processing. If possible, I'd like also to know where the peaks are located.

As the density estimation may contain very small local changes, I'd like to have the possibility of adjusting the "sensitivity". The best I could find so far was this solution of @Tommy : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836924/1003358 Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- density(faithful$eruptions, bw = "sj")
loc.max <- d$x[localMaxima(d$y)]

ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions)) + geom_density(adjust=1/2) +
  geom_vline(x=loc.max, col="red") +
  xlab("Measured values")
```

[image: Identifying maxima in faithful dataset]

Now, my data are much noisier:

```
d <- density(my.df$Values, bw = "sj")
loc.max <- d$x[localMaxima(d$y)]

ggplot(my.df, aes(Values)) + geom_density(adjust=1/2) +
  geom_vline(x=loc.max, col="red") +
  xlab("Measured values")
```

[image: First attempt to identify maxima in my dataset]

Trying to adjust the parameters (note that two "unwanted" peaks in the tail have been found):

```
d <- density(my.df$Values, bw="nrd", adjust=1.2)
loc.max <- d$x[localMaxima(d$y)]

ggplot(my.df, aes(Values)) + geom_density(adjust=1/2) +
  geom_vline(x=loc.max, col="red") +
  xlab("Measured values")
```

[image: Second attempt to detect peaks in my dataset]

So the questions are:

1) How to automatically identify real peaks within such a noisy dataset?
2) How to reliably find the pits that separate those peaks?

Comment: How do you define "real peaks"?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein That's a good question. I'm having difficulties to grasp this concept mathematically. There should be a particular window around the peak within which this peak is the largest value. Additionally, a cut-off for the minimum peak size (maybe in relation to the median) might help. If I know my data is bimodal, the two highest peaks with a reasonably (I admit, this is again vague) large window should result. If I don't know the number of peaks in advance,maybe a cut-off for the max. value of a pit separating the peaks together with a cut-off for the min. value of a peak would help?

Comment: Analysis of spectral data (chromatographic or photometric) often have this problem, so you might see if including "spectr*" in your searches for peak identification.  @cbeleites is both an SO participant and involved in active R package development along those lines.

Comment: @DWin Thanks for your suggestion! That way I've found a Bioconductor-package called "PROcess" for spectra processing that seems to yield acceptable results.

Comment: You should post a simple worked example.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is `pastecs::turnpoints` .  But you're correct that you'll have to do some subjective filtering to distinguish spiky noise from true peaks.  One way to do this is to require either the raw or splined data to remain above some threshold for N consecutive values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. `pastecs::turnpoints` doesn't seem to offer the possibility to define a span/window, so again I face the same problem as with the approach above. I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion to define such a threshold. Also, as far as I understand, it doesn't distinguish between peaks and pits, does it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've just noticed that you can distinguish peaks from pits with the `extract()` method. I'll definitely have a closer look at this function. But I'm still wondering what's the best way to filter the values.