# Given an empirical probability density function, how to find the value (in R) at which the density peaks?

Tags: r, probability-density

I calculate the density function for the following data:

```
> dput(mydat)  
c(-20, -13, 30, 4, -4, 34, 27, 19, 13.5, 15, 13, 18, 10, 12, 
21, -0.769999999999996, 2.5, -7, 0, -30.6, 6.39999999999999, 
-18.6, -0.199999999999989, -20.4, -19.9, 4.60000000000001, -19.4, 
4.5, -9, -15, 9, -1, -14, 8, 6, -17, 5, 7)  

> myden = density(mydat)  # default kernel and bandwidth
```

which gives me this result:

[image]

I want to find the location of the two density peaks. I initially thought of using `diff()` on `myden$y` and then check for all locations where there is a sign change, using this as a condition to select the X-axis values. I tried it on a few test vectors but I was not getting the expected result and I suspect it is not that simplistic.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? I want a solution that will be repeatable because I will do this as part of a random simulation study with ~ e+05 realisations, and it could happen that the number of peaks vary across the simulation.

Comment: Why do you think the diff() approach isn't working as expected? I just saw the diff output and where the sign changes from +ve to -ve seems to be around a peak. Diff should approximate the differential sort of logic one would normally apply to get the local maxima.

Comment: @Thomas  thanks! yes, its a duplicate. it will have to be flagged as such and i dont know if i have the privileges to do that.

Comment: @Codoremifa after looking at the link Thomas posted, i remembered from calculus class that one has to test this with the second differential..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use `pastecs::turnpoints` to find local maxima and minima.

Comment: E.g., http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30750/11849

Comment: @Roland  where's that "I posted it" disclaimer?  :-)  //shuffles off to link to his own `turnpoints` posts  *_O

Comment: `turnpoints` works like a charm. However, I can imagine that for noisy data (similar to what is written on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319826/finding-local-maxima-minima-in-r/14320172#14320172), I might have to look for a work-around..But thats a different matter and for now, this should work.

Comment: If your data is noisy, just smooth it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `which.max`:

```
myden$x[which.max(myden$y)]
# [1] 5.91428
```

You can test this visually:

```
plot(myden, col='red')
abline(v=myden$x[which.max(myden$y)])
```

[image]

Comment: I want to find the value for both (or multiple, if there are more) peaks, not just the global maximum..

Comment: @AdvaitGodbole Ah, then see the question and answers I just posted on your original question.