# Retrieve values of local maxima in R data table - already have column numbers

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

using this question's solution: [Finding local maxima and minima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima) I have been able to retrieve what seems to be a list of column numbers from my data table for local maxima. I also need to retrieve the value of that peak from the table. Preferably I would return a matrix or equivalent where each row contains the local peak values rather than the positions, as I already have the positions

so say using a vector ex_data <-c(1,3,2,2,1,3,5,4,2,1) I would want to get a vector saying (3,5).
I already have the code below:

```
local_max <- function(x) {
which(diff(sign(diff(x)))==-2)+1}
local_max(ex_data)
```

which produces vector (2,7)

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible. Read the post [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. Just use the index vector for subsetting.

```
ex_data[local_max(ex_data)]
```

Comment: So simple, thank you! I've done this type of thing in python a hundred times but R is a mystery to me at the moment!