# Function to label local extrema in ggplot2 line graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a time series and I would like to automatically label specific points such as the last point, and local extrema, the highest and lowest.

How would I wrap this in a function to automatically label key points. Specifically by adding more local extrema.

Here is an example dataset:

```
latest <- structure(list(ReleaseDate = structure(c(1363928400, 1364533200, 
1365138000, 1365742800, 1366347600, 1366952400, 1367557200, 1368162000, 
1368766800, 1369371600, 1369976400, 1370581200, 1371186000, 1371790800, 
1372395600, 1373000400, 1373605200, 1374210000, 1374814800, 1375419600, 
1376024400, 1376629200, 1377234000, 1377838800, 1378443600, 1379048400, 
1379653200, 1380258000, 1380862800, 1381467600, 1382072400, 1382677200, 
1383282000, 1383890400, 1384495200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Count = c(1746L, 1748L, 1738L, 1771L, 1758L, 
1754L, 1764L, 1769L, 1769L, 1762L, 1771L, 1765L, 1771L, 1759L, 
1748L, 1757L, 1759L, 1770L, 1776L, 1782L, 1778L, 1791L, 1776L, 
1776L, 1767L, 1768L, 1761L, 1744L, 1756L, 1743L, 1739L, 1738L, 
1742L, 1754L, 1762L)), .Names = c("ReleaseDate", "Count"), row.names = 150:184, class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
libary(ddply)

last <- tail(latest, 1)
high <- subset(latest, Count == max(Count))
mid <- subset(latest[5:20,], Count == min(Count))

ggplot(latest, aes(ReleaseDate, Count)) + geom_line()  + 
  geom_text(data = last, aes(ReleaseDate, Count), label = last$Count, vjust = -1) + 
  geom_text(data = high, aes(ReleaseDate, Count), label = high$Count, vjust = -.1) + 
  geom_text(data = mid, aes(ReleaseDate, Count), label = mid$Count, vjust = 1)
```

Here I've attempted to manually add specific points, but it would not be concise if I wanted to add 10 labels to a longer series.

Comment: What are your criteria for local extrema?

Comment: Search SO with: [r] find local maximum

Comment: You may get ideas for editing your question to be specific enough to be answered by working through answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima