# What is meant by local minima and maxima in Digital Image Processing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, minima

Can Someone please explain the concept of local minima and maxima in terms of digital image processing...

Comment: The same as in any other context: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth is correct. If you want to know how to find local minima/maxima, look at:  [finding-local-maxima-and-minima](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima)

Comment: @hellfire769 I am not asking about how to find local minima/ maxima, What I want to know is concept that its minima and maxima of what quantity?

Comment: It depends on what context you are using this in.  Local minima and maxima is used for edge gradients in non-minimum edge suppression in Canny edge detectors in order to weed out weak edges.  You can also use this for filtering out noise by taking local minima and maxima of the graylevel intensities themselves.  The concept of minima and maxima is no different than what you're used to, but it **depends** on **where** you are using it.  Depending on where you're using it, you apply the principle to different information about images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a digital image, your minima are the darkest pixels and maxima, conversley, the brightest pixels.