# How to subset the data to surrounding rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with two columns:

```
dd <- read.table(text = "
344 0 
350 16 
366  11 
376   8 
380  28 
397  55
398  45  
400  19 
402  30
408  20
415   0
")
```

I want to subset the data between the two minimum local around the highest value in the second column (`55`).

The result will be:

```
376   8 
380  28 
397  55
398  45  
400  19
```

It must contain a minimum local function because the dimension of sub-data frame is variable

```
dd <- read.table(text = "
460  0 
461  2 
463  16 
469  33 
471 13 
473 23 
479 38 
480 168 
481  0")
```

Comment: Why have you excluded `0` while looking for minimum around `max` value?

Answer (score 2):

Subsetting to N surrounding values should be as easy as that:

```
p.max <- which.max(dd$V2)
range <- -2:2
dd[p.max + range, ]

#   V1 V2
# 4 376  8
# 5 380 28
# 6 397 55
# 7 398 45
# 8 400 19
```

To subset between the local minimums around the global maximum you can do something like this:

```
dd <- read.table(text = "344 0 
350 16 
366  11 
376   8 
380  28 
397  55
396  50
398  45  
400  19 
402  30
408  20
415   0")

library(data.table)
minimums <- function(x) which(x - shift(x, 1) < 0  & x - shift(x, 1, type='lead') < 0)
p.max <- which.max(dd$V2)
local.mins <- minimums(dd$V2)
local.mins <- c(last(local.mins[local.mins < p.max]), first(local.mins[local.mins > p.max]))
dd[local.mins[1]:local.mins[2], ]
```

Here I have used `data.table` because it has some useful functions like `shift` and `first`.

`minimums` function was taken from answer to this question: [Finding local maxima and minima in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205515/finding-local-maxima-and-minima-in-r)

This code does not seem to work for cases where local minimum does not exist, e.g. min value is last or first.

Comment: It must contain a fonction for minimum local. It's not always between -2 and +2

Comment: well, you need to give another example in that case, your description + example were not clear

Comment: I added another example

Comment: I have updated the answer