# How to find all the turning points on a kernel density curve when window width varies

Tags: r, kernel, curve, turning-point

I want to partition a data series using kernel density. Here is my plan:

1. Using kernel density function (like density()) with variant window width to calculate the density of this series.
2. On every kernel curve with different window width, I find all the turning points (including minimal and maximal) to partition the data.

So, I need to know where those turning points are in the original data series. I read some information like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30750/finding-local-extrema-of-a-density-function-using-splines. But I do not really understand the method. In that method, d$x[tp$tppos] looks not the original index. So how can I find the positions of all the turning points in the original data based on kernel density curve?

Another related question is: how to find all the minimal/maximal points?

A sample of data series is:

```
a <- c(21.11606, 15.22204, 16.27281, 15.22204, 15.22204, 21.11606, 19.32840, 15.22204, 20.25594, 15.22204, 14.28352, 15.22195, 19.32840, 19.32840, 15.22204, 14.28352, 21.11606, 21.19069, 15.22204, 25.26564, 15.22204, 19.32840, 21.11606, 15.22204, 15.22204, 19.32840, 15.22204, 19.32840, 15.22204, 15.22204, 21.13656, 15.22204, 15.22204, 19.32840, 15.22204, 17.98954, 15.22204, 15.22204, 15.22204, 15.22204, 15.22204, 19.32840, 15.22204, 14.28352, 15.22204, 19.32840, 15.22204, 19.32840, 25.42281, 21.19069)
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6836409/5967807) has some excellent answers that might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take density of a:   `Da = density(a)`   the result has the y values associated with many x's.  That is where the plot comes from. To find the "turning points",  you need to find the places that the derivative changes sign. Since the x values given in Da$x are increasing, Each
`Da$y[i] - Da$y[i-1]` has the same sign as the derivative at the i<sup>th</sup> point. You can find where these change sign by finding where the product of consecutive values is negative. So, putting this all together, we get:

```
Da = density(a)
DeltaY = diff(Da$y)
Turns = which(DeltaY[-1] * DeltaY[-length(DeltaY)] < 0) + 1

plot(Da, xlab="", ylab="", main="")
points(Da$x[Turns], Da$y[Turns], pch=16, col="red")
```

[image: Density Plot with Extrema]

You can get different "window widths" using the `adjust` parameter to `density`. However, you are going to find that as you make `adjust` smaller,  the density plot will develop *many* maxima and minima.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I still do not know how to find the turning points in the original data. For example, Turns = [126,198,257,370,408]. But a just has 50 points. So, how can I find the points related to the index in Turns? One more thing is: the index in Turns includes minimal and maximal. How can I just find minimal, or maximal?

Comment: @FengChen Use `Da = density(a, n = length(a))` for `Turns` to reflect indices in `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very important to me!