# Count values of same kind in a row and omit interruptions

Tags: r

my actual problem is, that I want to count the length of similar values in my vector, for example:

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2)
```

But additionally I want to omit all interruptions with the length 1.
How can I achieve that my result here would be:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2
```

Note that the single "two" should now turn in a "one" and with

```
v_new <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2)

rle(v_new)
lengths: int [1:4] 7 3 2 3 
values : num [1:4] 1 3 1 2
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: If that first 2 was followed by, say two 4s - what would be the expected output then?

Comment: "similar values" meaning "equal values"?

Comment: yes, "equal values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> v <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2)
> 
> local.peak <- which(diff(sign(diff(v)))==-2) + 1
> 
> v[which(diff(sign(diff(v)))==-2) + 1] <- v[local.peak - 1]
> v
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 2
```

The local peak function is taken from [Finding local maxima and minima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima][1])

Answer (score 1):

Below is a little function that replaces values that occur not more than one time in a row with either the value to the left or right of it.

Your input

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2)
fun(v)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 2
```

Modified input

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,2,4,4,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2)
#                ^ ^
```

Usage

```
fun(v, align = "right")
# [1] 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 2
```

Default is left aligned

```
fun(v)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 2
```

**function**

```
fun <- function(x, align = c("left", "right")) {
      align <- match.arg(align)
      rle_x <- rle(x)
      rle_x$values <- with(rle_x, replace(values, lengths == 1, NA))
      switch(align,
             left = approx(inverse.rle(rle_x), xout = seq_along(x), method = "constant", f = 0)$y,
             right = approx(inverse.rle(rle_x), xout = seq_along(x), method = "constant", f = 1)$y)
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much, exactly what I was searching for :)