# r: new variable duration of bout

Tags: r

I'm working with accelerometer data (the SB column) and would like to add a variable that counts the length of an activity bout e.g. sitting(SB), and restarts counting after the person got up ("SB_count").
In a second step, I would like to create a 2nd variable ("SB_bout" which only keeps the final bout length values.

I've been stuck on this for a while, probably because I was using the wrong search terms, so I would really appreaciate it, if someone could point me in the right direction.

This is what it should look like:

```
      SB      SB_count  SB_bout
1     1       1         0
2     1       2         0
3     1       3         3
4     0       0         0
5     1       1         0
6     1       2         2
```

Comment: Do you have any data to start with? What is your starting point?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not clarifying this. What I have is the SB-column.

Comment: Does SB-bout need to be 0 for each row except the maximum value? Or can it show the maximum value of that run for every row in that run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I cracked it using your toy example. For SB_bout I used [@Tommy's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima) for finding local peaks in a vector. 
I think it should do the trick for other data you may have in this format, but you should have a look at the specifics of the function nevertheless.

```
Data <- data.frame(SB = c(1,1,1,0,1,1))

Data$SB_count <- ave(Data$SB, cumsum(Data$SB==0), FUN=cumsum)

# Find peaks function
localMaxima <- function(x) {
  # Use -Inf instead if x is numeric (non-integer)
  y <- diff(c(-.Machine$integer.max, x)) > 0L
  rle(y)$lengths
  y <- cumsum(rle(y)$lengths)
  y <- y[seq.int(1L, length(y), 2L)]
  if (x[[1]] == x[[2]]) {
    y <- y[-1]
  }
  y
}

Data$SB_bout <- Data$SB_count
Data$SB_bout[-localMaxima(Data$SB_count)] <- 0

Data

  SB SB_count SB_bout
1  1        1       0
2  1        2       0
3  1        3       3
4  0        0       0
5  1        1       0
6  1        2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using `rle`, `fill` and `mutate`.
First created your starting point:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

SB <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(SB)
```

Then added the `SB_count` using `rle`. I also needed a `run` number in order to group afterwards:

```
df$SB_count <- sequence(rle(df$SB)$lengths)
df$SB_count[df$SB == 0] <- 0
nstarts <- length(df$SB_count[df$SB_count == 1])
df$run[df$SB_count == 1] <- 1:nstarts
df <- fill(df, run)
df <- df[,c(3,1:2)]
```

Finally grouping by `run` and adding the `max` value:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(run) %>%
  mutate(SB_bout = max(SB_count))

df$run[df$SB == 0] <- 0
df$SB_bout[df$SB == 0] <- 0
```

This gives the following output:

```
    run    SB SB_count SB_bout
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1        1       3
2     1     1        2       3
3     1     1        3       3
4     0     0        0       0
5     2     1        1       2
6     2     1        2       2
```

The only difference with yours is that I'm showing the maximum `SB_bout` in every row of that `run`.