# Detect peaks at beginning and end of x-axis

Tags: r, detection, smoothing

I've been working on detecting peaks within a data set of thousands of y~x relationships. Thanks to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36309/how-do-i-find-peaks-in-a-dataset), I've been using `loess` and `rollapply` to detect peaks by comparing the local maximum to the smooth. Since, I've been working to optimise the `span` and `w` thresholds for `loess` and `rollapply` functions, respectively.

However, I have realised that several of my relationships have a peak at the beginning or the end on the x-axis, which are of my interest. But these peaks are not being identified. For now, I've tried to add fake variables outside of my x variable range to imitate a peak. For example, if my x values range from -50 to 160, I created x values of -100 and 210 and assigned a 0 y value to them.

This helped me to identify some of the relationships that have a peak at the beginning or the end. As you can see here:

[image]

However, for some it does not work.

[image] [image]

Despite the fact that I feel uncomfortable adding 'fake' values to the relationship, the smoothing shifts the location of the peak frequently and more importantly, I cannot find a solution that allows to detect these beginning or end peaks. Does anyone know how to work out a solution that works in R?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6836409/10488504 - Finding local maxima and minima

Comment: thanks, I checked and tried the first answer but it's the same issue. It does not detect maxima if they are at the beginning or the end.

Comment: EDIT: I'm trying @Tommy's answer and it seems more promising!