# How to find local minima with the rollapply function?

Tags: r, zoo

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836955), I'm trying to find the local minima of a function. Here is what I'm doing:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(zoo)

x <- seq(0, 25, by=0.1)
y <- sin(x)

my.df <- data.frame(x, y)

xz <- as.zoo(y)
rxz <- zoo::rollapply(xz, width = 20, align = "center", function(x) which.min(x)==2)

indexes <- index(rxz)[coredata(rxz)]
indexes

ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + geom_vline(xintercept = my.df$x[indexes])
```

Plotting the results gives:

[image]

I guess the x offset is due to the width I use, but can't figure out why this happens, as rollapply supposed to use a centred rolling window.

Comment: Tangent: you're using `require` wrong: it never stops following code when the package is not available, which is almost never what is intended. Either use `require` and check the return value, or use `library`. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Generally, I don't use require in my functions because they are within a package that imports the necessary dependencies with roxygen. I only use it to provide working snippets. I'll use library from now on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Based on @IceCreamToucan's comment, your use of `==2` might be more appropriate as `10` or `11`, due to your width of 20.
2. To mitigate the problem of determine which of 10 or 11 is more appropriate (since you have an even-width kernel), I suggest an odd-width kernel.

```r
wid <- 21L
ceiling(wid/2)
# [1] 11
rxz <- zoo::rollapply(y, width = 21, align = "center", function(x) which.min(x) == ceiling(wid/2), fill = FALSE)
ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + geom_vline(xintercept = x[rxz])
```

[image: ggplot2 highlighting local minima]

Note that I'm intentionally setting the width programmatically to preclude the possibility of inconsistency between `rollapply` and the inner function call. (I'm inferring that that may be what happened to you: you initially had a width of 3 or 4, where `== 2` was more meaningful. I may be wrong, it's just a guess :-)