# Finding local maximum and minimum R

Tags: r, math

I have a list of values that I want to identify local maximum and minimuma with. Theres just over 1000 numbers in total.

This is a subset of some of my numbers:

```
c(76.4734833333333, 76.4700041666667, 76.4705916666667, 76.4693, 
76.4679, 76.4675208333333, 76.4666833333333, 76.4655291666667, 
76.46565, 76.4668125, 76.4618416666667, 76.4617666666667, 76.466375, 
76.4636708333333, 76.464325, 76.4638833333333, 76.4633083333333, 
76.4627333333333, 76.4605541666667, 76.4601708333333, 76.4625583333333, 
76.46265, 76.4607833333333, 76.4604730769231, 76.4611833333333, 
76.4607291666667, 76.4613375, 76.4598166666667, 76.4579916666667, 
76.4593, 76.4573291666667, 76.4560208333333, 76.4555958333333, 
76.4544916666667, 76.4549875, 76.45485, 76.4542708333333, 76.4576333333333, 
76.4551708333333, 76.4562208333333, 76.4550291666667, 76.4525125, 
76.45145, 76.4581166666667, 76.4509125, 76.4506875, 76.4480791666667, 
76.4469083333333, 76.446825, 76.4456666666667, 76.4450833333333, 
76.4471166666667, 76.4454583333333, 76.4565958333333, 76.4572708333333, 
76.4527166666667, 76.4499791666667, 76.4462416666667, 76.4470125, 
76.4436833333333, 76.4394083333333, 76.4384083333333, 76.4380416666667, 
76.4420916666667, 76.4388541666667, 76.4417416666667, 76.4382791666667, 
76.4415875, 76.4379041666667, 76.4356916666667, 76.437425, 76.4351666666667, 
76.4323208333333, 76.4308708333333, 76.4279583333333, 76.42345, 
76.4236708333333, 76.4214541666667, 76.4135166666667, 76.4157791666667, 
76.4080083333333, 76.4109583333333, 76.4063458333333, 76.4014958333333, 
76.3932291666667, 76.3864208333333, 76.3806208333333, 76.3771708333333, 
76.3774375, 76.4234958333333, 76.424825, 76.4310833333333, 76.4348666666667, 
76.4300916666667, 76.4245625, 76.4180791666667, 76.4292083333333, 
76.4327583333333, 76.4309416666667, 76.4186708333333, 76.4252375, 
76.4248, 76.4411958333333, 76.4403166666667, 76.449325, 76.4444291666667, 
76.4322291666667, 76.4382, 76.4252083333333, 76.4230583333333, 
76.42185, 76.4090375, 76.4278958333333, 76.4500083333333, 76.4380541666667, 
76.4399125)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'd like to have a column in my dataframe of whether something is a maximum or minimum point. I.e. 1 = max, 0=neither, -1 = min.

I have seen this. But I dont know how to convert the numbers into a column. [Finding local maxima and minima](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6836409/18143306)

##### My answer based on above:

(df$mAOD is the same as the list provided above).
Although I'm not sure its capturing everything properly.

```
max <- which(diff(sign(diff(df$mAOD)))==-2)+1
df$max <- ifelse(seq_len(nrow(df)) %in% max, 1, NA)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding local maxima and minima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima)

Comment: @GordonShumway I've added a slight edit to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
# make pairs of sign of "derivative" in the manner of sliding window 
p <- embed(sign(diff(v)), 2)
# checks if the sum of each pair of "derivative" equals to 0 (local maximum/minimum results in a sign changes, such that the sum of two adjacent signs should be 0)
idx <- which(rowSums(p) == 0) + 1

plot(v, type = "l")
points(idx, v[idx], col = "red")
```

and you will see the local maximum and minimum (highlighted in red) in the following plot

[image]

Comment: Hi would you mind just explaining what the two first lines are actually doing? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `pracma`package, as it has functions for peak-detection (`findpeaks()`) that is quite easy to use. With it and e.g. inverting your data-points (to find the minima) you can perhaps build a function that serves your needs.